# How to check every word in Python

Tags: python, replace, split, cpu-word

I want to replace words in string. But my problems is that when I want replace wordA to wordB and wordB to wordA. They replace each other.
I can do

```
line.split()
```

But in that case I will lose white-space. So what should be the correct way to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it in three steps:

```
import re

my_string = "some words i other words oraz last words"
# choose some phrase that does not appear in the original string
temp = "##########"
# replace the word 'i' with that temp string
my_string = re.sub(r'\bi\b', temp, my_string)
# replace the word 'oraz' with 'i', like normal
my_string = re.sub(r'\boraz\b', 'i', my_string)
# replace the temp string with 'oraz'
my_string = re.sub(temp, 'oraz', my_string)

print(my_string)
# 'some words oraz other words i last words'
```

---

Alternatively, you could do it in one expression if you used a lambda as the replacement, and chose to return `'i'` or `'oraz'` conditionally:

```
my_string = "some words i other words oraz last words"

my_string = re.sub(
    r'\b(i|oraz)\b', 
    lambda rg:'i' if rg.group(0) == 'oraz' else 'oraz', 
    my_string
)

print(my_string)
# 'some words oraz other words i last words'
```

Comment: So easy solution, thank you very much